# Jenkins text parameter rebuild

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the text parameter to get multi line parameters, and write them to file.
If I use the rebuild, the text parameter is loaded as a single line string (where newline is removed).

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? I guess the rebuild plugin is the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multi-line text parameter seems to be [rather buggy](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Multi-line-default-values-for-new-quot-text-parameter-quot-in-Jenkins-1-418-td3629222.html). One workaround you may consider is to substitute newlines with some custom escape system and then convert the escape sequences back to newlines inside your build.

A more advanced solution would be to modify the plugin itself to convert the escape sequences into newlines and use that modified plugin in your Jenkins. I've done that sort of thing for [Claim Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) to display failed matrix jobs which it did not do on its own. If you decide to take this route I can walk you through the main steps.

Comment: Fair enough... I will accept this as the harsh reality :-). Thx for the reply. I have the option of not supporting the use of the rebuild in this particular instance of Jenkins, so I'll not use it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have just enhanced the plugin to add `TextParameterValue.jelly`
That works fine, since text and textarea are not that different except new lines just use `StringParameterValue.jelly` as template and use  `<f:textarea name="value" value="${it.value}" />` instead of  `<f:textbox name="value" value="${it.value}" />`